# Can't see install disc for Linux Mint in VirtualBox

Tags: macos, install, unix, virtualbox

Trying to install Mint 17 Cinnamon via VirtualBox on my MBP OSX10.9.4, with  3 different discs (various makes) made on several machines (Win and Linux). I was able to deploy vm with CentOS 6.4 with a similarly made disc without problems. Mint discs get rejected with error "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you are downloading the ISO file and burning it to a CD or DVD. This isn't necessary.

Download the ISO file from the Mint website.

Then within VirtualBox create a new VM entering the various properties like memory size,  hard drive, etc.

Once the VM is created, open up the Settings for the VM, go to the Storage tab and select the Empty CD drive. Click the light CD image on the right hand side and select "Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file...". Then locate and select the ISO image you downloaded from the Mint website.

[image: The Storage tab of the Settings dialog in VirtualBox]

Close the Settings dialog and Start the VM. The installer should load and run to start your install.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Was not aware I had that option. Thank you